# Kubernetes - Changing autoscaling default version from autoscaling/v1 to autoscaling/v2beta2

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am using Kubernetes v1.22.2. I am trying to implement HorizontalPodAutoscaler but with api version autoscaling/v2beta2 as I want to implement autoscaling feature using ram and cpu resource.

To implement k8s in my CICD pipeline using Jenkins I am using [Kubernetes Continues Deploy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-cd/) and [Kubernetes](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/) plugin. When I am trying to deploy using jenkins I am getting following error ,

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException:
> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure
> executing: POST at:
> https://MY_IP:6443/apis/autoscaling/v1/namespaces/default/horizontalpodautoscalers.
> Message: the API version in the data (autoscaling/v2beta2) does not
> match the expected API version (autoscaling/v1). Received status:
> Status(apiVersion=v1, code=400, details=null, kind=Status, message=the
> API version in the data (autoscaling/v2beta2) does not match the
> expected API version (autoscaling/v1),
> metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null,
> additionalProperties={}), reason=BadRequest, status=Failure,
> additionalProperties={}).     at
> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:472)
> at
> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.assertResponseCode(OperationSupport.java:411)
> at
> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:381)
> at
> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:344)
> at
> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleCreate(OperationSupport.java:227)
> at
> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:780)
> at
> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.create(BaseOperation.java:349)

Here is the output from my k8s master ,

```
kubectl api-versions | grep autoscaling
autoscaling/v1
autoscaling/v2beta1
autoscaling/v2beta2
```

Here is my hba file ,

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: getuser
spec:
  behavior:
    scaleDown:
      stabilizationWindowSeconds: 300
      policies:
      - type: Pods
        value: 1
        periodSeconds: 15
  maxReplicas: 3
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: getuser
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 55
```

How do I enable or set default api version for autoscaling apart from autoscaling/v1 ?

Comment: Share your hpa kube config yaml file.

Comment: How exactly did you set up your cluster,? Please also share your config files.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak I have used https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/  this link for installation.

Comment: Hmm, based on [this github topic](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71556) it is working as expected and you should use `autoscaling/v1`. Did you see it?

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor I skipped the above mentioned plugins and did is with sshAgent plugin. Initially I was getting  "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?" this error. This got resolved when I mentioned location of the config file in command like this. sudo kubectl apply --kubeconfig=/home/akgk/.kube/config -f deployment.yaml